# Smallest $p$ such that $2\mid\operatorname{ord}(a)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, cyclotomic-polynomials

Fix a constant $a$. Then consider primes $p$ and the sequence

$$a^1-1, a^2-1, a^3-1, a^4-1,...,a^N-1.$$

We say a prime $p$ is a primitive divisor of $a^m-1$ if it divides $a^m-1$ and does not divide $a^j-1$ for $j<m$. Clearly if $N\geq p-1$, then $p$ is primitive divisor of $a^m-1$ for some $m$ in the above sequence. But it is not so clear what more we can say for a particular $p$. I am specifically interested in the partial or full answers to the following question:

For any given $a$, what is the smallest $k$ such that $\exists p<k$ with $p$ a primitive divisor of $a^{2m}-1$ for some $2m<N$?

Alternatively phrased, what is the smallest $p$ with $2|ord(a)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

I can see some basic results such as that $k\leq a+1$ for any $a$ and $N$ (as $a+1$ is a primitive divisor of $a^2-1$ which is at most prime). Also given certain modular conditions on $a$ we can say $k<a^{1/2}$ via reciprocity (as the smallest quadratic nonresidue mod $a$ will be less than $a^{1/2}$).

Can we do better? Is there known literature on this?

Comment: What is a primitive divisor? Do you mean prime divisor?

Comment: edited to include definition

Comment: I feel like the effective versions of chebatarov density theorem could be used here — but I don’t know how to apply them

Comment: In the question "*For any given a, what is the smallest $k$ such that there exists $p<k$ with $p$ a primitive divisor of $a^{2m−1}$ for some $2m<N$?*" there are a lot of unclear variables. Please introduce them one by one. What is $N$? What is $m$? Why do we need $k$? (And not set $k=p+1$ instead...) There are a lot of questions, but there is no example, no real attempt to solve them. There is also no context for the questions, why are they important? Why should one first fix some $a$, and some few powers, then look for a "good finite field for them". Why we do not directly work with $a^2$?